# Is the home directory modifed at all during an upgrade of Xubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu

I have a number of encrypted home directories on Xubuntu 13.10 (x86_64). I plan to upgrade to Xubuntu 14.04; I will be doing that from the admin's home directory.

Will the upgrade affect the home directory of the other users?

Will those users with encrypted home be asked to do anything else after the upgrade, to finalize the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

As a result of upgrading, data inside users' home directories will not be modified.

However, as a result of modifications to individual pieces of software, some software may manipulate files in the user's home directory when that user runs that software for the first time after upgrading.  For example, something which stores its config in ~/.config/ or its cache in ~/.cache/ may modify the format of its configuration or cache after noticing that the previously generated files were from an older version.